# Upload image file and save to server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to upload an image and then save it to the server file system using Shiny.

To upload I've found

```
fileInput
```

which creates a data.frame containing the image details and datapath.  How then can this be used to save to a remote server?

Comment: On the UI side, when you state something like `fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
         '.csv'))`, the object `input$file1` will be your file on the server side. You can work with that file from there, store it (e.g. `write()`) or post it to a remote server via SFTP, cloud services or else. You might want to read this: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html - and here an upload example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is basic example. It only copy the uploaded file to at location on server. In this is in the same computer, but it could be anywhere.

```R
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(  
    fluidRow( 
      fileInput("myFile", "Choose a file", accept = c('image/png', 'image/jpeg'))
    )
  ),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
    observeEvent(input$myFile, {
      inFile <- input$myFile
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return()
      file.copy(inFile$datapath, file.path("c:/temp", inFile$name) )
    })
  })
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```